# EF 4.1 Code First Mapping two columns in one table to list

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm having an issue figuring out how to make this work for EF 4.1 Code First.  I've looked around and found a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472214/ef-code-first-mapping-for-collection), but I couldn't get it to work for me and it sounds like it didn't get answered for this person either.

Here is a simplified version of the two objects in question.

```
public class Team
{
  public int TeamId {get; set;}
  public virtual IList<Game> Games {get; set;}
}

public class Game
{
  public int GameId {get; set; }
  public int AwayTeamId {get; set;}
  public int HomeTeamId {get; set;}

  public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
  public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }  
}
```

And here is my code for registering the FKs

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
        .HasRequired(a => a.HomeTeam)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.HomeTeamId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
        .HasRequired(a => a.AwayTeam)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.AwayTeamId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

I want to bring back all games (home or away) that a team is in.  Right now EF is creating a TeamId column in my database that never gets populated.  If what I want is impossible, then I could do lists of HomeGames and AwayGames and another list of Games that is a combination of the two, but I'd like to try and avoid it if possible.  I'm still learning this so any extra explanations or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Here was a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155953/ef-4-1-multiple-many-to-many-relationships-in-single-class/6156615#6156615 Basically your own proposal is the right way to go. It's impossible to map two endpoints on one side to a single endpoint on the other side of an association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF is not able to map two relations into single navigation property. Your additional `TeamId` column is created because `Games` navigation property is considered as separate relation (your mapping says that neither `HomeTeam` or `AwayTeam` are part of that relation) so you instructed EF to create three relations for your.

You must define your model this way:

```
public class Team
{
  public int TeamId {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Game> HomeGames { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Game> AwayGames { get; set; }
}
```

And mapping must be:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
        .HasRequired(a => a.HomeTeam)
        .WithMany(t => t.HomeGames)
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.HomeTeamId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
        .HasRequired(a => a.AwayTeam)
        .WithMany(t => t.AwayGames)
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.AwayTeamId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Now if you want all team's games you can use simply:

```
var games = team.HomeGames.Concat(team.AwayGames);
```

You can wrap this into method returning `IEnumerable` or into property with just getter returning `IEnumerable`.

Comment: This is exactly the code that I ended up implementing, with a property called GetGames that returned an IEnumerable of the combined HomeGames and AwayGames.  I did stumble because at first I used IList instead of IEnumerable and it was still creating the TeamId column in the database.  Once I switched it to IEnumerable, the column stopped coming back.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking of EF is a read only collection, i.e., an add operation would be meaningless for such a collection since EF wouldnt know into which table to insert, which I believe is unsupported.

Judging by your problem description, I would so something similar to your own suggestion and create a method such as GetGames() which would return just a unioned set of both home and away games.  I think this is conceptually cleaner anyway.